# Minimum Value in range based on 2 critiria vba excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, min, vba

I am trying to find the minimum date in a column based on 2 criteria.
It is similar to this formula;

```
=MIN(IF(D11:D1943=A1952,IF(E11:E1943=A1953,H11:H1943)))
```

but I would like to do it in vba code.  What is the equivalent line in vba that achieves this?

I am trying this with defined ranges but vba does not have the if functionality?

```
Cell.Offset(0, 0) = WorksheetFunction.MIN(IF(AccountIDRng=Cell.Offset(0,-1),IF(SeriesRng=Cell.Offset(0,-2),DateRng)))"
```

Comment: Are those VBA range variables, or named ranges?

Comment: vba declared range variables

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach, if i understood right than you can run the criteria first using this If and then the `Cell.Offset(0,0)` will only assume the value you want if thoes two criterias are ok, like this:

```
If AccountIDRng = Cell.Offset(0,-1) and SeriesRng = Cell.Offset(0,-2) then

Cell.Offset(0, 0) = worksheetFunction.Min("put your range here")

End If
```

Comment: Thanks but I am getting a Runtime 13 error  type mismatch.
Do I have to set the variable ranges as variants or something here?

Comment: i've created the code according to what you posted so all the variables are according to your original code, so you must check if:
1 -  all your variables are declared correct
2 -  the Cell you used on the code, is it a variable? if not then you must declare cell address on it like this Cells(rowindex , columnindex)

Answer (score 0):

For range variables, you could use Evaluate:

```
Cell.Value = Cell.Worksheet.Evaluate("MIN(IF(" & AccountIDRng.Address & "=" & Cell.Offset(0,-1).Address & ",IF(" & SeriesRng.Address & "=" & Cell.Offset(0,-2).Address & "," & DateRng.Address & ")))"
```

Or if you really want, you could use something like this:

```
Cell.Value = Application.Min(Application.Choose(Application.Power(2, Application.GeStep(Application.CountIfs(cell.Offset(, -1), AccountIDRng, cell.Offset(, -2), SeriesRng), 1)), 1E+100, DateRng))
```

which will return 1E100 if there are no matches, not 0.

For maintainability, I'd probably go with Evaluate, or looping code. ;)